# Returning XML in OkObjectResult in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I've got some prepackaged XML string that I want to return from a static function that returns an IActionResult. Note that this is not a controller or anything - it's for an Azure Function.

The XML is as follows:

```xml
<Test code="0"><MyChild>123</MyChild></Test>
```

So to store this XML as a string, I need to escape the quotes in order to store the code properly, e.g.

```
"<Test code=\"0\"><MyChild>123</MyChild></Test>"
```

How do I then call

```cs
return new OkObjectResult(myxml)
```

I am having trouble with all manner of the XML helpers in System.Xml. For instance, I tried:

```cs
XmlDocument xmltest = new XmlDocument();
xmltest.LoadXml(myxml);
return new OkObjectResult(xmltest);
```

But all I get is the following error:

> System.Private.DataContractSerialization: Type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' with data contract name 'XmlElement:[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml'](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml%27) is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return XML, instead of using `OkObjectResult`, return a new instance of `ContentResult`.

```
return new ContentResult()
{
    Content = xmlDocument.InnerXml,
    ContentType = "text/xml",
    StatusCode = 200
};
```

You don't need to return the status code either, I believe **200** is defaulted if left blank.

Ultimately, **OkObjectResult** will serialize the object you’ve provided and return that in the response body as JSON, but, that’s ok for objects where the structure is what you want to return.

In relation to an XML document, it’s not the object you want to serialize, it’s the XML itself which, is already kinda serialized when you think about it.

If you returned the XML through OkObjectResult, it would be represented as a string.

Hence why using the **ContentResult** approach is the best way to go because you can control all of those key parameters that make up the response body.